# is runOnUiThread will create new thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading

Can any one explain, is `runOnUiThread` will create new thread?. or it will work on current thread

```
someActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
});
```

Comment: It will run on the `main` Thread which is the `UI` Thread in android. Basically if you have to do UI-related things you are going to use that method.

Answer (score 5):

No, it won't create any new thread. The action you specify will run on the UI thread of your application. You can post actions from other threads (background threads) to run on the UI thread. (Like updating views, etc which you have to do on the UI thread).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 1):

Your UI-Thread is always running. And this method just run on your existing UI-Thread. So, no Thread will be created.

Answer (score 0):

I test it using sleep function, the log show that it is the same thread.

```
05-31 08:47:06.481 6538-6538/com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp I/MainActivity: onPause: 
05-31 08:47:07.888 6538-6538/com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp I/MainActivity: onStop: 
05-31 08:47:07.893 6538-6538/com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp I/MainActivity: onDestroy: 
05-31 08:47:10.294 6538-6538/com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp I/MainActivity: run: in
05-31 08:47:25.315 6538-6538/com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp I/MainActivity: run: out
05-31 08:47:25.362 6538-6538/com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp I/MainActivity: onStart: 
05-31 08:47:25.366 6538-6538/com.example.languoguang.welcomeapp I/MainActivity: onResume:
```

Toast in thread use runOnUiThread:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textView = $(R.id.main_text);
        if (textView != null) {
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        initializeStartButton();
        initializeSetButton();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "run: in");
                    Thread.sleep(15000);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Thread", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(TAG, "run: out");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, "onCreate: ", e);
    }
}
```

Add, runOnUiThread signature:

```
/**
 * Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is the UI
 * thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current thread is
 * not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue of the UI thread.
 *
 * @param action the action to run on the UI thread
 */
@Override
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action) {
    if (Thread.currentThread() != mUiThread) {
        mHandler.post(action);
    } else {
        action.run();
    }
}
```